# updating a row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to update a row in a table to the previous row with indexing.  I am having trouble updating my real dataset and cannot reproduce the error on a toy example.

```python
gd.loc[gd['Date'] == ts,teams] = gd.loc[gd['Date'] == tsPrevious,teams]
```

Here is a picture of the problem.

[image]

The row where `Date==ts` should be updated to the row where `Date==tsPrevious`.  The screenshot shows the dates, the row I want to use to update, and the row I want to update.  The last code block is my attempt to update row ts to the row for `tsPrevious`.  But you can see the row associated with `ts` is unchanged.

This code is a toy example and in the following screenshot, you see it works as expected:

```python
testDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Col1", "Col2","Col3"])
testDF["Col1"] = [1,2]
testDF.iloc[0,1] = 7
print(testDF)

testDF.loc[1,1:2] = testDF.iloc[0,1:2]
print(testDF)
```

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, error messages, tracebacks, warnings, etc. - just copy/paste them into a code block.

Comment: You may find the warning _"Whether a copy or a reference is returned for a setting operation, may depend on the context. This is sometimes called chained assignment and should be avoided. See Returning a View versus Copy."_ at [_"Selection by position"_ Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) useful.

Comment: Here is the code from the first screenshot in case it helps.  The other lines in the screenshot are just to show you what these variables are.

gd.loc[gd['Date'] == ts,teams] = gd.loc[gd['Date'] == tsPrevious,teams]

I didn't get an error or warning with the code in the first screenshot - the dataframe just didn't update, which is what the image is trying to capture.  I included the toy example code with the screenshot in case that helps troubleshoot...

Answer (score 2):

Your example is different from your original problem. Here's something closer:

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

testDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
testDF["Col1"] = [1, 2]
testDF.iloc[0, 1] = 7

# This doesn't work
testDF.loc[testDF["Col1"] == 2, cols[1:]] = testDF.loc[testDF["Col1"] == 1, cols[1:]]
```

When you're assigning with `.loc`, Pandas will only make the assignment where the indices are aligned. In this example, you're trying to set index 1, but on the right side you only have index 0, so it doesn't to anything.

To overcome this, you can access the values of the row using `.values`:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

testDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
testDF["Col1"] = [1, 2]
testDF.iloc[0, 1] = 7

# This works
testDF.loc[testDF["Col1"] == 2, cols[1:]] = testDF.loc[testDF["Col1"] == 1, cols[1:]].values
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked.  The better alignment of the toy example and the original problem was helpful.  And I think I understand what you are saying about alignment.  Did you mean to say that I'm trying to set index 1 and on the right is index 0?  If so, I understand, and if not, maybe I'm still confused.

Comment: Also, can you point me to documentation on when I need to use ".value"?  I'm trying to figure out the general rule here.  (I've tried google and didn't find it - maybe not sure of the keywords to use...)  And thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @Grace Yes, you're right, I've mistyped the numbers. You're trying to set index 1 but the selection on the right only has index 0.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics

Comment: Note that the docs recommend using `.to_numpy()`, which is the same as using `.values`, just more descriptive of the type of values it returns (a numpy array).